# how to copy file from android assets folder into android document directory path

Tags: react-native

I am trying to copy file from android assets folder into android document directory path.

I test the folder existence using 
RNFS.existsAssets('offlinereader').then((result) => console.log(result));
 The result is true
I copy the folder into DocumentDirectoryPath using

RNFS.copyFileAssets('offlinereader', RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+'offlinereader') .then((result) => console.log(result)) .catch((error) => console.log(error));

but iam getting error "offlinereader couldnot be opened"

Comment: Have u got solution for this issue @ jeevitha aiyappa